# Basic SSL Certificate Questions

Tags: ssl, azure, ssl-certificate

It has been a long time since I purchased a SSL Certificate for a web site and I am confused on what I need. There are a lot of options and I can't filter out what is really needed verse what are optional premium services. Would really like to hear from your experience what is important to you when purchasing a SSL Cert.

Some of my questions are:

- How important is it to have 40 bit minimum vs. 128 bit minimum encryption?
- Is organization validation important
  if this is going to be a B2B site?
- Is the warranty/insurance important
  at all? Is this just a marketing
  scheme? How many people really
  collect on this?
- The site is going to be Windows Azure
  should this matter in my decision?

Thanks in advance for your answers!!

Comment: Your certificate has nothing to do with 40 or 128 bit encryption. That is controlled by the ciphersuites you and your peer agree to use in the negotiation phase of the SSL connection.

Comment: This might be more on-topic on [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com) or [serverfault](http://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 11):

- GoDaddy SSL certificates are cheap and are great for any small to medium size business endeavor.
- Get the organization validation options if you are doing millions of dollars a year in transactions.  IMO it's not that important or critical as a buyer
- Standard SSL will allow you to do   secure.yourdomain.com  OR www.yourdomain.com OR some single domain name. Get a wildcard if you plan on doing more like  client1.yourdomain.com  or client2.yourdomain.com
- Warranty / Insurance - no need
- As for Azure here is a step by step process for doing your [Azure SSL certificate](http://sondreb.com/blog/post/Windows-Azure-Secure-Site-with-SSL-certificate.aspx)

The low cost GoDaddy certificates work fine for 99.9% scenarios and they are like $20 to $30 dollars versus $300+

Comment: Please correct/remove your first point. As GregS mentioned in his comment to the question the 40/128 bit encryption of SSL/TLS doesn't have anything to do with the certificate itself. I'd rather recommend buying a RSA certificate with at least 2048 bit. A certificate with 1024 bit or less isn't considered to be secure anymore. RSA keys with more than 2048 are nice to have. However, they come with the disadvandage of slower TLS handshakes since the certificate that has to be transfered between client and server is larger.

Answer (score 1):

Biggest thing is to ensure you can get the format in PFX. I purchased mine from RapidSSL and unfortunately it has been the biggest pain getting it to a PFX file. Don't go through the hours wasted like I had to.